# Add events to calendar php

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I am developing my own calendar with events. Everything has been doing well but now I have some problems.

This is my code:

```
    <?php

    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cMonth, 1, $cYear);

    $maxday = date("t", $timestamp);
    $thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
    $thisyear = getdate($timestamp);
    $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($maxday + $startday); $i++) {
        $date = ($i - $startday + 1) . $cMonth . $cYear;

        if (($i % 7) == 0)
            ;

        if ($i < $startday)
            ;
        elseif (($i - $startday + 1) == $cDay && $cMonth && $cYear) {
            echo "<div class='currentDate'>" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "<br /></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='?day=" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "&month=" . $cMonth . "&year=" . $cYear . "'><div class='date'>" . ($i - $startday + 1) . "</div></a>";
        }

        $result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM events");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $event_date2 = $row['event_date'];
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($event_date2));

            if (($i - $startday + 1) == $date2) { // Check if the date is the same 
                echo "<div class='date'><a href='#'>" . $date2 . "</a></div>"; // Show the event date.
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I am trying to match every day in the calendar with dates from the table "events" in MySQL. Every date in the calendar that have a matching date in events should show this event.

**EDIT: The rest of the code:**

```
     <?php
        $monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");



        if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
        if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");



        $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
        $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];



        if(!isset($_REQUEST['day'])) $_REQUEST['day'] = date('d');
        if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
        if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

  // Rest of code
        $cDay =  $_REQUEST['day'];
        $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
        $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];




        // Rest of code

        ?>
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: The problem is that my code shows every date from "event_date".

Comment: Are the date fields in your db stored as timestamp, datetime or date ?

Comment: They are stored as date

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you fetch all the events without filtering them by date. You should add a condition in your query to fetch only the events that happen on a certain date :

```
$result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date = '2015-12-30'");
```

for example.

In my opinion, you should fetch all the events of the month in the first place with one request, and then display your calendar. You could also use DateTime objects which make it easyer to deal with dates in php

> http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

First of all, you could set your dates :

```
$monthInterval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$dayInterval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$dateStart = new \DateTime();
$dateStart->setDate($cYear, $cMonth, 1);
$dateEnd = clone $dateStart;
// We set the date end to be the first day of the next month
$dateEnd->add($monthInterval);
```

Then you could fetch all the events of the month

```
$events = [];
$result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= '" . $dateStart->format('Y-m-d') . "' AND event_date <= '" . $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d') . "'");

// We create a multidimentional array with all the events of the month
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
}
```

And then you can display your calendar :

```
$currentDate = clone $dateStart;
while ($currentDate < $dateEnd) {
    // the date is available with the $currentDate variable
    ... do what you want for each day

    // If you want to get the events of the day, just check if they exist :
    $currentDateFormat = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
    if (isset($events[$currentDateFormat]) {
        // Then you can loop through your daily events :
        foreach ($events[$currentDateFormat] as $event) {
            ....
        }
    }

    // We add one day to the current date to step to the next one
    $currentDate->add($dayInterval);
}
```

Beware that if you store date fields as timestamps or datetime, you will have to adapt my code as it is implemented to work with date fields.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your help. I'm trying to make it work but i got an error saying "Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in...". 

I will publish rest of my code and maybe you can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I edited my code, I cloned a non existent object, but you could have seen that ($dateEnd = clone $dateStart;)

Comment: Okay, sorry, now I see that.

Comment: Now I get "Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in..."
Everything is correct now so do you have any ideas? Really appreciate your help and sorry but I am trying to learn.

Comment: I edited my answer : $result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= '" . $dateStart->format('Y-m-d') . "' AND event_date <= '" . $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d') . "'");